# Compared to natural gem formation, does the decreased pressure when forming flame fusion gems affect crystal structure (different system entropy)?

Tags: pressure, entropy, crystals

Do the synthetic gems (flame fusion type) have the same crystal structure as a natural gem or is it a less perfect crystal lattice? Because they are not formed at the same pressures I'm wondering how the disparate entropies of the two systems affects crystal defects. I would think the decreased pressure would increase the entropy and thus create more crystal defects and weaken the lattice. (as an aside would this change the hardness of the gem)

Comment: Wikipedia notes the crystals are chemically and physically identical. Growth striations might be distinctive however.

Comment: it also talks about growth lines which are structurally different between the two

Comment: Those would be the striations.